# printing to windows printer with python or shell command

Tags: python, windows

I'm tryin to script an annoying task that involves fetching, handling and printing loads of scanned docs - jpeg or pdf. I don't succeed in accessing the printer from python or from windows shell (which I could script with python subproccess module). I succeeded in printing a text file from the command line with lpr command, but not jpg or pdf.

be glad for any clues about that, including a more extensive win shell reference for printing to printer, a suitable python library I missed in my google search stackoverflow search etc (just one [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850949/printing-from-python-using-lpr-or-win32))

Comment: I used this for a rtf (just an idea) : subprocess.call(['loffice', '-pt', 'LaserJet', file])

Comment: I tshould work for a pdf at least.

Comment: thanks I'll try that - but please explain why? what is loffice command?  and you should write in as an answer - so you could be awarded the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a little research I found some links that might help you:

1) To print images using Python Shell, this link below has some code using PIL that will, hopefully, do what you want:
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

2) To print PDF files, this link may have what you need:
http://www.darkcoding.net/software/printing-word-and-pdf-files-from-python/

I never did any of those things, but with a quick look, I could find this links and they seem to make very much sense. Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks, I'll check that - but I suspect since my main problem is jpg this won't help.. nothing to lose with trying

Comment: doesn't really solve my problem but upvoted for the research and for the lead

Comment: Thank you! I saw many other search results that people use Python Shell to print a bunch of files, but always with another program to send the file to the printer. I guess it makes sense, since some file formats are proprietary and other are very peculiar, which Python can't deal with them yet. And maybe this happens because a lack of libraries that could handle them properly...

Comment: actually my solution involved both your idea and @f-p workaround, so I decided to award the points to a newbie here. happy hunting

Comment: Another must read [material](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/usbprint.html) shows more methods and introduces windows utilities to print from windows shell

Answer (score 1):

I used this for a rtf (just an idea) :

```
subprocess.call(['loffice', '-pt', 'LaserJet', file])
```

I am using [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/). it can print in a batch mode.

Comment: ah, this is the catch, It involves actually calling Libreoffice to do the printing .. I don't this this is the highway for me, and also suspect it works for rtf but not jpg or pdf..

Comment: For pdf it does, and you have to call something anyway.

Comment: won't use it but upvoted for the clever work around ,I'll do something like this with something lighter (Infranview?)

Answer (score 1):

with a default pdf viewer assigned to the system you can do

```
 import win32api
 fname="C:\\somePDF.pdf"
 win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", fname, None,  ".",  0)
```

note that this will only work on windows and will not work with all pdf viewers but it should be good with acrobat and Foxit and several other major ones.

Comment: Hi @Joran am able to print directly, when I try using win32api, raises the exception error: (31, 'ShellExecute', 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')
Do have idea?

Answer (score 0):

My brohter showed me another way to print using `cmd` (on windows) but I guess it could work for any OS.

In this case it worked for me using VScode as environment:

1. get the filepath.

```
import os

myfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Foldername","Filename.pdf")
    open_file = open(myfile, "rb")
```

2. Identify the command of your OS to print from the command source (like cmd):

```
command = "Start-Process -FilePath " + '\"' + myfile +'\"' + " -Verb Print"
```

3. Get the output method in python. I used `import subprocess` module method.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["powershell", command], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
```

This script will allow you to print making a connection from python to `cmd` and from cmd to python again. Also, I had to make a `.bat` file to execute the testing program because VScode do not execute with all permissions. the file contains the following command (works like if its the `cmd`)

`python.exe filepath\myfile.py`

just executing the bat file will execute the program correctly.