# How to read excel quickly?

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I have a xls file which is 67M,126000 rows and I want to import it into sqlite database as  quickly as possible.

Now I have two solutions which are implemented with python:

1. Use xlrd to read excel and sqlite3 to insert into database; (*It costs about 28s*)
2. Use adodbapi to read excel and sqlite3 to insert into database; (*It cost about 33s*)

I hope it can be done within 20s.Do you have any other solutions? Programming language must be Python or C/C++, because I want to integrate it into Python program.

Comment: would it be possible to export it as a CSV and read that? I am not sure, but maybe it is quicker?

Comment: I have my doubts if you can do it much faster, considering that we are taling about 126 k rows. But agree with javex: get it into csv first. Load it from csv and use this as a benchmark for further activities and a reality check.

Comment: You can use [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) to convert to csv. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11749459/1117641)

Answer (score 0):

Use [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/). it can convert in a batch mode:

```
subprocess.call(['loffice', '--invisible', '--convert-to', 'csv', file])
```

It is worth a try maybe?

Comment: At last I chose to optimize my solutions 2(use adodbapi to read excel).Because the method _getValue() of _SQLrow  always converts the value of that row.In my program, It doesn't help. So I just use the raw data from SQL(ado_results attribute of _SQLrows ).It does make my program run faster.

Answer (score 0):

use pandas to do this. it is very fast
two steps are involved here.
1. to import excel file as a dataframe
2. export the dataframe to sql

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')   #Connection to Database

df = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx')   #Reading from excel file

df.to_sql(name='table_of_database', con=conn)  # Writing to SQL
conn.close()
```

I know it will be fast. but please tell me the elapsed time after excecuting, as I have not evaluated for 67M data.